# Andengine + Box2d. Remove sprite, when it isn't visible for user

Tags: android, box2d, andengine, sprite

I write some wallpaper. It represents the many sprites which fall down. When its fly out of screen I want to detach them from Scene. How can I do this optimally?
Now I use this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < getScene().getChildCount(); i++) {
    if (i < getScene().getChildCount())
        removeSprite((Sprite) getScene().getChildByIndex(i));
}

private boolean removeSprite(final Sprite sprite) {
    if ((sprite.getX()>CAMERA_WIDTH+sprite.getWidth()*2 || sprite.getX()<-sprite.getWidth()*2) && (sprite.getY()>CAMERA_HEIGHT+sprite.getHeight()*2 || sprite.getY()<0-sprite.getWidth()*2)) {
        final PhysicsConnector spritePhysicsConnector = physicsWorld.getPhysicsConnectorManager().findPhysicsConnectorByShape(sprite);

        physicsWorld.unregisterPhysicsConnector(spritePhysicsConnector);
        physicsWorld.destroyBody(spritePhysicsConnector.getBody());

        getScene().unregisterTouchArea(sprite);
        getScene().detachChild(sprite);

    } 
}
```

But its not right way. What are the best solutions exist?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable culling on Sprite object. That way it won't be rendered when it's out of screen.